# WindowServer crashing after Big Sur update when connected to external monitor (LG UltraFine Display)

Tags: mac, crash, big-sur

Since I upgraded to Big Sur my computer is crashing even couple of times per day when connected to external monitor (LG UltraFine Display 27-inch). Here is the crash log:

```
Process:               WindowServer [144]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               600.00 (588.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           WindowServer [144]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2021-06-08 14:10:51.444 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.4 (18P4663)
Anonymous UUID:        D27DD82A-D166-4C34-5F35-F0B25F144F8C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       7F3635CD-71C4-4CD9-BB94-F59541B66C81

Time Awake Since Boot: 24000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       20000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    WATCHDOG, [0x1] monitoring timed out for service
Termination Details:   WATCHDOG, checkin with service: WindowServer returned not alive with context:
unresponsive work processor(s): WindowServer main thread 
40 seconds since last successful checkin, 2073 total successsful checkins since wake (0 induced crashes)

Application Specific Information:
StartTime:2021-06-07 19:19:24
GPU:IG&AMD
MetalDevice for accelerator(0xbeaf): 0x7f90bc142e08 (MTLDevice: 0x7f9090008000)
MetalDevice for accelerator(0xcc17): 0x7f90bc1408c8 (MTLDevice: 0x7f9070028000)
IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG0@1/IOPP/EGP0@0/IOPP/EGP1@0/IOPP/GFX0@0/AMDRadeonX6000_AmdRadeonControllerNavi14/ATY,Boa@1
boot-args: 

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff22dcf793 io_connect_method + 384
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff22dcf5af IOConnectCallMethod + 186
4   com.apple.driver.IOAccelerator2D    0x00000001072e8b32 0x1072e5000 + 15154
5   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff21926cd9 MPSelectMode(CGXDisplayDevice*, CGDisplayMode*, CoreDisplay::DisplayOutputMode, CGXSelectModeOption) + 1005
6   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff21939cc3 complete_connect_change + 626
7   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff21937c6e displayConnectChange + 5129
8   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff218a29f6 IOFBInterestCallback(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 521
9   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff22dd169a IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 315
10  com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff21935b33 displayNotification + 604
11  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff2514c59d post_port_data + 265
12  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff2514c1f1 CGXRunOneServicesPass + 1719
13  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff2514cf83 server_loop + 91
14  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fff2514cd55 SLXServer + 1889
15  WindowServer                    0x0000000104244320 0x104241000 + 13088
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20636f5d start + 1

Thread 1:: com.apple.coreanimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff26ebddcc CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 498
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff26ebdbc7 thread_fun(void*) + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061b8fc _pthread_start + 224
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617443 thread_start + 15

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.VirtualDisplayListener
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205ee863 mach_msg_server_once + 255
3   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff2189c5d1 -[VirtualDisplayListener rx] + 77
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20470623 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20471806 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff204775ea _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff204780ad _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20481c0d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061845d _pthread_wqthread + 314
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061742f start_wqthread + 15

Thread 3:: IOHIDService - RunLoopCompatibilityThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20714b5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2071323f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2071264c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20798f52 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff22e20b77 __IOHIDServiceRunLoopCompatibilityThread + 306
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061b8fc _pthread_start + 224
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617443 thread_start + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20714b5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2071323f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2071264c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20798f52 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   com.apple.hid.AppleHIDALSServicePlugin  0x00000001069d4bca void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, AppleUSBALS::scheduleWithDispatchQueue(dispatch_queue_s*)::$_0> >(void*) + 222
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061b8fc _pthread_start + 224
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617443 thread_start + 15

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20714b5f __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 316
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2071323f __CFRunLoopRun + 1328
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2071264c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20798f52 CFRunLoopRun + 40
6   com.apple.hid.AppleHIDALSServicePlugin  0x00000001069d4bca void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, AppleUSBALS::scheduleWithDispatchQueue(dispatch_queue_s*)::$_0> >(void*) + 222
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061b8fc _pthread_start + 224
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617443 thread_start + 15

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e62ba mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff205e662c mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff2197bf01 CoreDisplay::Mach::Server::Start() + 147
3   com.apple.CoreDisplay           0x00007fff2197c069 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (CoreDisplay::Mach::Server::*)(), CoreDisplay::Mach::Server*> >(void*) + 59
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff2061b8fc _pthread_start + 224
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617443 thread_start + 15

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617420 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20617420 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000003  rcx: 0x00007ffeeb9ac7f8  rdx: 0x000000000000005c
  rdi: 0x00007ffeeb9ac878  rsi: 0x0000000000000003  rbp: 0x00007ffeeb9ac850  rsp: 0x00007ffeeb9ac7f8
   r8: 0x0000000000000607   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00000000000010bc  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000003  r13: 0x00000000000010bc  r14: 0x00007ffeeb9ac878  r15: 0x000000000000005c
  rip: 0x00007fff205e62ba  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00000001a7b7a000
```

Everything works correctly when I disconnect the monitor.

My macOS configuration:

[image]